# さくらサーバーでメールのみ利用時に独自ドメインでメールサーバーへ接続できない

Tags: dns, mail

お世話になります。
現在、さくらサーバーで下記の挙動の試験をしています。
Aレコードを外部サーバーに向け、MXレコードをさくらサーバーへ向けると、
さくらで与えられる初期ドメインではメールを見ることができるのですが、独自ドメインではメールが見られなくなる原因がわからない状態です。

> さくらのドメイン: example.com
>   WEB用サーバー: 192.168.0.0（仮）
>   さくらのサーバー（メール用）: 192.168.0.1（仮） / 初期ドメイン: www.0000.sakura.ne.jp

初期のexample.comをすべてさくらサーバーへ向けている状態では、メールサーバーを「example.com」としていても、「www.0000.sakura.ne.jp」としてもメールサーバーへ接続できますが、下記のような設定でAレコードを外部サーバーへ向けると、example.comではメールサーバーにアクセスできなくなります。

```
@ IN NS ns1.dns.ne.jp
@ IN NS ns2.dns.ne.jp
@ IN A 192.168.0.0
@ IN MX 10 mail
www IN CNAME @
mail IN A 192.168.0.1
ftp IN CNAME @
```

運用上は初期ドメインで設定すれば良いので問題ないですが、仕組みや独自ドメインでもメールサーバーへアクセスする方法があれば知りたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

--- 追記 ---
example.comではメールサーバーにアクセスできなくなります。についてですが、
Macの標準メールクライアントを利用して、メールアカウントの設定ができなくなります。

試験的にfirst@example.comとsecond@example.comを作成し、
Macの標準メールクライアントで、
first@example.comでは、メールサーバーを「example.com」、
second@example.comでは、メールサーバーを「www.0000.sakura.ne.jp」
と設定した状態で、DNSを変更しています。

さくらドメインからさくらサーバーへの初期設定では、first@、second@ともにメール受信ができていますが、
DNSを上記のものに変更すると、first@ではアカウントエラーになりメールサーバーへ接続ができなくなります。（さくらのオンラインWEBメーラーではメールが確認できます）

メールクライアントとメールサーバーとの接続の確立する際に、Aレコードを参照するために接続ができない？と予想していますが、そうした場合WEBサーバーとメールサーバーを同じドメインで分ける方法が思いつきませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「example.comではメールサーバーにアクセスできなくなります。」の具体的な状況や、名前解決について確認した内容とその結果について、質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: ありがとうございます。本文へ試した内容を追記いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メールソフトは192.168.0.1のサーバに接続すればよいのですよね？

mail.example.comや192.168.0.1を指定すればよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 返信おくれてすみませんでした。顧客側のメールクライアントの設定が変更できないという条件で作業をしていましたが、結果顧客側のメールクライアント設定をすべて変更する方法で対応しましたので解決いたしました。